# Alternative to overriding Render for adding ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference attribute in nested GridViews

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, nested

Is there an alternative to overriding the page render method to make my gridview rows clickable. This works fine in single grid view mode, but when nested , although the code steps through and seems ok, I don't get the selected index firing on the nested grid view.

Edit: I have tried the following line in RowDataBound, but don't know why I don't get the selected index firing

```
e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(e.Row.Parent.Parent, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
```

---

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    if (gdvServiceSchedule.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gdvServiceSchedule.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

                    row.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this.gdvServiceSchedule, "Select$" + row.DataItemIndex, true)); 
            }
            if (row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit || row.RowState == (DataControlRowState.Edit | DataControlRowState.Alternate))
            {
                GridView gv = (GridView)row.FindControl("gdvServiceScheduleVariants");
                if(gv.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach(GridViewRow row2 in gv.Rows)
                    {
                        if(row2.RowType ==DataControlRowType.DataRow)

                        {
                            row2.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(row.FindControl("gdvServiceScheduleVariants"), "Select$" + row2.DataItemIndex, true)); 
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    base.Render(writer);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the MVC framework... but seriously, can you just create another of your custom control inside of the row instead of a GridView?

Comment: There are a couple of ways around the problem that I see, one of them could be a custom control, I just want to know the solution to the problem. :)